# Why do I need Windows Authentication? my Anonymous Authentication is broken

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7

Even default ASPNET websites seem to require Windows Authentication enabled on my machine when Anonymous Authentication should do, what could be wrong with my IIS7/ASP.NET install?

I've ran aspnet_regiis /i but it still does not not fix it!

I get 401.3

Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.

Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with Basic Authentication being disabled, by default.
Enabling this fixes the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the web user has access to the files.  File/folder permissions will override the anonymous option you pick in IIS.

Comment: The IIS_IUSRS (MyMachine\IIS_IUSRS) account actually has full control on the Websites directory!

Comment: Check that there are no overriding child permissions and that all the child folders are ser to inherit, check there are no deny permissions as they override allow permissions.  Also check effective permissions tab against the web user on a file that you think should be web accessable.